# Python subprocess stderr/stdout field is None if created

Tags: python, subprocess

When I create a python subprocess with a file stream as the `stderr` (or `stdout`), the corresponding field is `None`:

```
s = subprocess.Popen(['ls','qwer'],
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stderr=open("zzzzz",'wb'))
s.stderr is None
==> True
```

(I expected `s.stderr` to be the file stream).

- Is this documented/intentional?
- What is the rationale?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is intentional. When you provide the `stdout`/`stdin`/`stderr` kwargs to the [`Popen` constructor](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor), you're telling it where to direct those pipes in the child process:

> stdin, stdout and stderr specify the executed program’s standard
>   input, standard output and standard error file handles, respectively.

But the `stdout`/`stdin`/`stderr` properties on the `Popen` object [are documented as only having a value when you use `PIPE`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.stdin):

> **Popen.stdin**
>
> If the stdin argument was PIPE, this attribute is a file object that provides input to the child process. Otherwise, it is None.
>
> **Popen.stdout**
>
> If the stdout argument was PIPE, this attribute is a file object that provides output from the child process. Otherwise, it is None.
>
> **Popen.stderr**
>
> If the stderr argument was PIPE, this attribute is a file object that provides error output from the child process. Otherwise, it is
>   None.

As for why `Popen.std*` is `None` when you pass a handle other than `PIPE`, I'm not certain. Perhaps because it is considered redundant, since you had to pass an open handle to the constructor to begin with?